# CakePHP 2.1 - custom authorization object not loaded/executed

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.1

I'm using CakePHP 2.1 RC + [TinyAuthorize](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Controller/Component/Auth/TinyAuthorize.php), the next way in AppController.php:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array('Auth');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authorize = array('Tiny');
    }

}
```

For some reason, Tiny doesn't get executed, thereby it's ACL rules not applied. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I got the same problem with a custom authorization class. It seems that Cake is loading the class correctly (I get errors when I don't include a authenticate method), but Cake seems to be ignoring the code inside the custom class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you put it in app or tools plugin?
for the latter it is supposed to be

```
$this->Auth->authorize = array('Tools.Tiny');
```

see http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/ for details

---

After figuring out your problem I edit my answer:

This * (= any) placeholder for “roles” only refers to those users that are logged in. You must not declare your public actions this way! All those must be declared using $this->Auth->allow().

The reason is that Authenticate comes before Authorize. So without Authentication (logged in) there will never be any Authorization (check on roles).

Comment: In app. So "Tools." prefix not required.

Comment: you probably have to go into detail on what your exact setup is - including what kind of Role model you are using, what roles etc. how does your acl.ini look?

Comment: User belongs to Role, Role has many Users.
acl.ini is never read, since for some reason TinyAuthorize.php not executed. Other than that - it's fresh CakePHP 2.1 installation.

Users table does have role_id field.

Comment: is the role_id also in the Session? Auth.User.role_id? did you accidently put $this->Auth->allow() somewhere?

Comment: Nope, and what's i expect it to do, is to make work a rule like this:

[Users]
login,signup = *

but it doesn't, all existing actions keep redirecting me to login action as if TinyAuthorize was not in effect

Comment: did you debug the cached acl.ini in `/tmp/cache/persistent`? what does it resolve the * to? (the file should be called `cake_core_tiny_auth_acl` - you can unserialize it with http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/index.php)

Comment: As I said before TinyAuthorize didn't execute, so nothing from this class in persistent cache folder.

Comment: well, my guess is that you forgot the basics. login/logout and at least one type of authentication module: `$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form'));`
this is also mentioned in the blog post, by the way...

Comment: mentioned things are at place

Comment: where did you state what authenticate type you use? your code example cleary lacks this essential line of code. please note that AUTHENTICATE != AUTHORIZE. two very different things.

Comment: I understand that difference (http://pastebin.com/qP8rcNuw), but things doesn't work for me (wasted 6 hours today already trying to make it work).

Comment: ahhhh - i think I understand what do did wrong... jesus^^
you must declare public actions with `$this->Auth->allow('action')` in your controllers. that is described both in the book and the tiny blog tutorial pretty clearly. this has nothing to do with those authorize modules. The `*` is only for LOGGED IN users which already have a role assigned.
In your case in your Users Controller:
`$this->Auth->allow('login', 'logout', 'register', ...');`

Comment: Yes, tho i've switched to Cake's PhpAcl, seems less troublemaking for me.